# Need htaccess redirect for subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a subdomain qa.test.com and codeigniter is installed on that subdomain, however I can't seem to get rid of the index.php in the url with this rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|user_guide|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Can someone help me with removing index.php from a subdomain type url.

Figured it out I did not have mod_rewrite enabled

sudo a2enmod rewrite and then restart apache

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: Which URL are you trying?

Comment: Codeigniter version is 2.1.x

Comment: Anubhava the url i am trying would be qa.test.com/login instead of qa.test.com/index.php/login

Comment: And are you getting 404 for `http://qa.test.com/login/` URL?

Comment: No I am getting a 500

Comment: For 500 you need to read Apache error.log to see what the error is.

Comment: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: ok that means mod_rewrite isn't enabled in your Apache config.

Comment: thanks anubhava figured it out

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|user_guide|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This is correct although you also have to have mod rewrite enabled, to enable mod rewrite run this command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and don't forget to restart apache

```
sudo service restart apache2
```